# How to specify a Rails 3 scope.limit - with an offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have some posts, and would like to show *n*..*m* most recent entries in the sidebar (these numbers being set in a config)

I can get the latest *n* records easily enough

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => "created_at DESC"
  scope :published, lambda { where("blog_entries.created_at <= ?", Time.zone.now) }
  scope :latest, lambda { |n| published.limit(n) }
end

@posts = Post.latest(6)
```

But what I'd like is

```
@posts = Post.published.limit(6, 12)
```

but this gives `wrong number of arguments`, so is there any way in AR? Right now I'm playing with `will_paginate`, but it seems hacky to use it for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is, I think:

```
@posts = Post.published.limit(6).offset(5)
```

It will retrieve 6 posts, starting from the sixth.

---

edit2: About the limit([6, 12]), I find that strange:

```
attr_accessor :limit_value

def limit(value)
  relation = clone
  relation.limit_value = value
  relation
end


def build_arel
    ...
    arel.take(connection.sanitize_limit(@limit_value)) if @limit_value
    ...
end


def sanitize_limit(limit)
    if limit.is_a?(Integer) || limit.is_a?(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral)
      limit
    elsif limit.to_s =~ /,/
      Arel.sql limit.to_s.split(',').map{ |i| Integer(i) }.join(',')
    else
      Integer(limit)
    end
  end
```

So I don't really see how it works with an array. But I obviously missed something. Do you see what?

Comment: well in the spirit of trying wild stabs in the dark I did `Post.limit([6,12])` and guess what, it works! so you were a little off but I'll give you credit :)

Comment: That's cool :) can you take a look at my edited post above and tell me if you see why it works with an array?

Comment: no I don't see how an array can slip through there. But where did you find this, in activerecord? my gem 3.0.3 doesn't have that at all, in `#build_arel` it has `arel = arel.take(@limit_value) if @limit_value` without the sanitation.

Answer (score 0):

For rails 5 (not sure for rails 4). `offset(x).limit(y)` works correctly. `limit(y).offset(x)` still behaves as described in other answers.